# gdb and valgrind within a makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gdb, valgrind

I have a very basic question. I did look around like over here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/ but still doubtfull..

Consider the following makefile(had also given it in a previous question)

```
all: clients.so simulator backup  
   LD_PRELOAD=/home/Juggler/client/clients.so ./simulator  
backup: backup.c libclient.a
   gcc backup.c -o backup -L /home/Juggler/client -L. -lclient -ldl 
simulator: simulator.c libclient.a     
   gcc -g simulator.c -o simulator -L /home/Juggler/client -L. -lclient -ldl -pthread
libclient.a: libclient.o client.o     
   ar rcs libclient.a libclient.o client.o 
libclient.o:libclient.c
   gcc -c libclient.c -o libclient.o -pthread  
clients.so: client.o client_invoke.o     
   ld -shared -o clients.so client_invoke.o client.o -ldl 
client_invoke.o: client_invoke.c     
   gcc -Wall -fPIC -DPIC -c -g client_invoke.c 
client.o: client.c
   gcc -Wall -fPIC -DPIC -c -g client.c -ldl -pthread
```

What do I do/change to debug using either gdb or valgrind. Actually I am getting a segmentation fault while doing make and would like to debug. But I have never used gdb or valgrind from within a makefile

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made a small edit to your presentation.  You originally wrote

```
client.o: client.c     gcc -Wall -fPIC -DPIC -c -g client.c -ldl -pthread
```

Can you change it to the new form and see if make segfaults?

Comment: :-( does not help. That was probably just a typing error on my part in th question that you edited

Answer (score 0):

normally I would do something to the effect of:

```
   $(DEBUGGER) ./simulator
```

then

```
$ make DEBUGGER=gdb --args
$ make DEBUGGER=valgrind
$ make # should still work without the debugger.
```

(technically the --args isn't needed for the command like it is, but if you add arguments to simulator in the future.)

but using LD_PRELOAD complicates this, because you probably don't want gdb loading libclient

```
   gdb -ex 'set env LD_PRELOAD=/home/Juggler/client/clients.so' -ex 'run' ./simulator
```

Additionally its normal to link shared libraries through gcc via gcc -shared -o client.so

Comment: does not seem to be working...Still getting segmentation fault but with no help from gdb

Comment: wasn't thinking about the LD_PRELOAD, i'm not sure if gdb supports the environment variable setting via `gdb LD_PRELOAD=... ./simulator' anyhow setting LD_PRELOAD to the gdb command is probably not a good idea, though it should be passed on to the 'simulator' command.

Answer (score 0):

One inelegant way would be to spawn the process via the makefile, and then attach to it with GDB in another terminal.  Using the trick from [linux: suspend process at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772922/linux-suspend-process-at-startup), you can launch the process and have it suspend immediately, and then connect with gdb.

have a script called launch.sh:
    #!/bin/bash

```
echo "Pid is $$"
echo -n "Press Enter.." 
read 
exec $@
```

have a makefile recipe like this:

```
whatever_target: whatever_deps
        ./launch.sh PROGRAM [ARGS]
```

if for some reason you can't see the output (like if you are redirecting), you can still get the PID via ps -ef or something.  then with gdb:

```
gdb PROGRAM_NAME PID
```