# How big is too big for static allocation of space

Tags: c, linux, arrays

As I could not find a way out using thread specific data for socket descriptor as depicted in this question [A question on shared library and thread specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460198/a-question-on-shared-library-and-thread-specific-data) , I am planning to declare a process wide global array with each row having two elements pthread_t and int(for socketfd). So whenever a thread needs to communicate with the server it will look up the array for its socket fd using its identity(pthread_self())and use it to communicate.

But I was wondering instead of dynamically allocating and deallocating space for this structure whenever there is a connection setup or disconnected respectively , if I have a array with the size of say 1000 ...is it too big/inefficient(I will have to search too)? 1000 threads will not exist at the same time. so the array will not always be full.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space required to store an array like this with only 1000 elements will not likely be a problem unless you're running on very resource limited hardware.  As for the performance, it really depends on how frequently you search the array... if the searches won't occur frequently during the life of each thread, the speed will probably be adequate unless you have very high standards for performance.

However, if you're planning on creating a thread for each connection and terminating the thread when done, then a better approach would be to design a structure containing all the information the thread needs from the main program (like the socket file descriptor) and pass a pointer to it as the thread's argument when you create the thread.

If you do use a thread per connection, you might also want to look into setting a smaller-than-default stack size for the threads as well, so that creating a large number of threads doesn't eat too much memory for stack space.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the memory required for 1000 elements multiplied by the space for a pthread_t and an int is insignificant, unless you are on an embedded computer or other similarly constrained system.

Regarding search time, a naive search through 1000 elements probably won't take very long. However you could make it really fast by implementing it as a [**hash table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

You might also consider though that although memory allocation is slow, creating new threads also is slow on most operating systems. (But you can use a [**thread pool**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) to avoid this.) Compared to the latter, the cost of memory allocation may be less than you think. And how often are you creating new threads compared to looking up that thread's context anyway?

One other comment: If you are really concerned about performance, then creating a separate thread to handle each connection is almost certainly not the way to go, because of the cost of context switches between the threads. Ideally you want to avoid context switches but keep all CPUs busy. That means you want the same number of threads as CPUs, and each thread doing asynchronous (non-blocking) I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Array will consume space but will be the fastest. Since 1000 elements can be fully bought into memory and wouldn't reside on disk as part of swapping by the OS, you will incur the cost of a cache miss at max. When multiple threads look up their information there is no cost incurred due to random access because the addresses of the 1000 rows are in sequence; not far apart for one another.

Additionally when you malloc() per row, each row you allocate need not be contiguous with the earlier allocated blocks and when multiple threads look up for their respective information there would be some kind of random access of memory involved due to this dynamic allocation.

Unless you have memory constraints, there is no need for using malloc(). Array approach is neat and performance friendly.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a single data structure shared between multiple threads is bad from the performance point of view if you need to update it from different threads. Updating the structure from one thread will force other CPU to invalidate their caches and synchronization primitives such as mutexes incur additional overhead and memory barriers. You can make it slightly better if you align elements to cache lines, but this is hardware-specific.

Having said that, I believe that this overhead will be negligible compared to the connection setup cost. But don't trust me, trust your profiler